# Firebase - TypeError: admin.auth(...).createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a user in firebase database using cloud functions. This is my code :

```
exports.AddUser = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, res){

    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        email = req.query.email;
        password = req.query.password;
        name = req.query.name;

        admin.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
            user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
                res.send("verification email sent.");
            }).catch(function(){
                res.end(user)
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
            res.send(errorMessage);
        });

    }else{
        email = req.body.email;
        password = req.body.password;
        name = req.body.name;

        admin.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
            user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
                res.send("verification email sent.");
            }).catch(function(error){
                res.end(user)
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
            res.send(errorMessage);
        });

    }

});
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

It works when I use `admin.createUser()` only but then I cannot use `user.sendEmailVerification()` because for some reasons its only available if the user is created using `admin.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

This is what I get in firebase console :

```
TypeError: admin.auth(...).createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function
    at /user_code/index.js:26:26
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:37:41)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:684:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:668:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

What do I do? Here,

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

I am new to firebase and cloud functions so apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message is telling you everything you need to know.  There is no method of that name in the node admin SDK.

You can see a list of all the methods on `admin.auth()` [in the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth).

createUserWithEmailAndPassword only exists [in the client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: So is there a way to send verification mail to the person if I use admin.auth().createUser() instead? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: No, you would have to manage that flow of information yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson the link to the API no longer works

Answer (score 9):

you just have to use **auth().createUser**  instead of  **createUserWithEmailAndPassword**

```
admin.auth().createUser({
 email: 'user@example.com',
 emailVerified: false,
 phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
 password: 'secretPassword',
 displayName: 'John Doe',
 photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
 disabled: false
})
.then(function(userRecord) {
  // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
  console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
})
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
 });
```

check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user